# Random array of 1's and 0's using methods

Tags: java, methods, random

I am trying to create a random sized array of 1's and 0's. I can get the program to run and compile if I remove the random aspect of the of it and enter the size of the array manually. For some reason when I bring in the random utility I can not get the program to compile.

mport java.util.Random;

```
public class Project1a {

    int[][] sample={{0,0,1,1,1},
                          {1,1,0,1,1},
                          {1,1,1,0,1},
                          {0,1,0,1,1}};

     int box[][];

    Random randomNumbers = new Random();


     int m = randomNumbers.nextInt(100);
     int n = randomNumbers.nextInt(100);


     int results[][] = new int [m][n];
     int goodData = 1;

   public  static void main(String[] args){
      analyzeTable();
      printTable(results);
   }

   public void analyzeTable() {
      int row=0;
      while (row < sample.length) {
         analyzeRow(row);
         row++;
      }
   }

   public void analyzeRow(int row) {
      int xCol = 0;
      int rCount = 0;
      while (xCol < sample[row].length) {
         rCount = analyzeCell(row,xCol);
         results[row][xCol] = rCount; 
         xCol++;
      }
   }

    int analyzeCell(int row, int col) {
      int xCol = col;   
      int runCount = 0;  
      int rowLen = sample[row].length;   
      int hereData = sample[row][xCol]; 
      while (hereData ==  goodData && xCol < rowLen) {
         runCount++;
         xCol++;
         if (xCol < rowLen) { hereData = sample[row][xCol];} 
      }
      return runCount;
   }

  public  void printTable(int[][] aTable ) {
    for (int[] row : aTable) {
      printRow(row);
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
  public void printRow(int[] aRow) {
    for (int cell  : aRow) {
      System.out.printf("%d ", cell);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: I renamed the class and now I get the following errors: cannot find symbol results for lines 22, 29,45 and the same for goodData line 55

Comment: yeah bcoz those variables are not accessible outside that block see my answer have provided detail

Comment: I fixed all that and now I get: non static method cannot be referenced from a static context. But if remove the static from the main I get the Main Method is static in class error

Comment: No you haven't changed all, check my answer I have mentioned there to declare `results` and `goodData` as static

Answer (score 2):

Your class name conflicts with `java.util.Random`. Renaming your class is the easiest fix here.

Comment: Another way would be to write `java.util.Random randomNumbers = new java.util.Random();`

Comment: It's a good practice not to create classes whose names are the same as `java.util.*` or `java.lang.*`. It'll confuse people. When someone sees `Random`, `String`, `List` or similarly-common names, they'll assume it's the JDK class.

Comment: it seems there are other problem as well alongside that class name confliction

Answer (score 0):

the problem is you are declaring your instance variable in a block which makes it in-accessible in methods

check this : **remove curly braces {  } from here** and the way you are accessing your `results` and `goodData` you need to declare them `static`

```
    { // remove this
Random randomNumbers = new Random();


int m = randomNumbers.nextInt(100);
int n = randomNumbers.nextInt(100);


 static int results = new int [m][n];   
 static int goodData = 1;
} // remove this
```